# Can wine and play on linux be installed in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: package-management, 16.04, dependencies

I'm upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 and having trouble installinging some items I used in the old OS.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could you [edit] the question and add the full error message you get.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You should make your question more clear and easier to understand, see as well [how to ask a good question](//askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be installed. The image below shows my version (16.04) and different packages currently installed, including Wine and PlayOnLinux.

[image]